# Gstreamer rtsp isn't picking up audio through queues

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

I'm having an issue with pulling audio and video from an RTSP stream using gstreamer.

The command I am using to test is as follows:
`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.50.160/whp name=src src. ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=10000 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.50.164 port=8004 src. ! queue ! fakesink`

The result of the above is that the pipe follows through for the first (video) stream. The second stream however is untouched and seems to sit in the rtspsrc plugin.

The way I am finding this is by looking at the resultant dot file:

[image: dot file]

If I am reading this right it looks like the queue connects correctly to rtpsession0, but seems to ignore rtpsession1 and the second queue doesn't connect to anything resulting in audio from my stream being completely ignored.

Am I reading this incorrectly? If not am I missing something in my pipeline command that would rectify this issue?

I am happy to provide any more information necessary

Thanks

Comment: This dot file looks like nothing is connected.. so the stream is not running at that point i assume?

Comment: ah it looks like I may have uploaded the wrong dot file, I will edit the post above with the correct one

Comment: Now there is an encoder in the dot file.. this and the pipeline you described don't match up either..

Comment: Apologies, I have been banging my head against the wall on this and have been getting confused with the numerous dot files and pipelines, I re-edited the question to reflect the dot file

Comment: So I believe in this dot graph the pipeline is not yet started. It needs to run before `rtspsrc` can expose actual stream pads.

Comment: so interestingly, when running this, the pipeline enters a PAUSED state and does not seem to recover. I know that if I run this with audio decoupled (only video) it pays without problem. it seems that adding the name and calling it is causing the video not to get picked up as active: see image below
https://imgur.com/a/GDmKgA7